# Drupal 8 - hook_mail doesn't get invoked

Tags: drupal-8

I'm trying to send a email with the **plugin.manager.mail**. The email gets send to the right address, but the **subject and body** are **empty**. ( I've checked, I put the **&** in front of **$message** so I reference to it.)

Then I checked with loggers, but my `MYMODULE_mail($key, &$message, $params)` **doesn't get called**.

Maybe some background, I'm using this in an EventSubscriber so I can monitor an action and then send the email. The eventSubscriber monitors the events from **Simple Fb Connect**

( https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/simple-fb-connect-8x/eventsubscriber-example )

**The link above links to the code I use**, so in the function `userLogin(GenericEvent $event)` I load my mailmanager and send the mail and in the same file I place the hook `MYMODULE_mail($key, &$message, $params) {}`

I have the feeling I'm placing this hook at the wrong place or naming it wrong. Can someone help me?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The hook MYMODULE_mail needs to be in the **MYMODULE.module** file and not in the same file where you monitor the events.
Clear cache and normally you're good to go